# iOS takes long time to update view after HTTP request?

Tags: ios, http, swift

I am very new to learning iOS and Swift, so there may be something very basic here that I don't understand. I am using the [agent](https://github.com/hallas/agent) library to send HTTP requests in Swift. Right now I'm just getting the hang of creating the request and parsing the JSON response.

I have a very simple UI with a button and a `UILabel` that I want to update with the results of some JSON.

Here is my code:

```
func updateWithJson() -> Void {
    let req = Agent.get("http://xkcd.com/info.0.json")
    req.end({ (response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, data: Agent.Data!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        let json = data! as Dictionary<NSString, NSString>
        // this takes almost 30 seconds to propagate to the UI...
        self.updateMe.text = json["safe_title"]!
    })
}
```

The part I don't understand is the `self.updateMe.text = json["safe_title"]!` statement which is just updating some text on a `UILabel` called `updateMe`. It takes almost a full 30 seconds for this to reflect in the UI.

I know that the HTTP request itself is very fast - if I curl that URL it comes back instantaneously. It also seems like the `Agent` object is making the connection and returning the response pretty fast.

Am I missing something very basic? Should I be updating the UI in a different way? All pointers are appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Through another SO post it's my understanding that the block inside of `req.end` is a background thread and I need to do UI updates on the main thread. I updated my function to look like this and I get the desired result. However, now I'm wondering if there's something incorrect about doing it this way?

```
    func updateWithJson() -> Void {
        let req = Agent.get("http://xkcd.com/info.0.json")
        req.end({ (response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, data: Agent.Data!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            let json = data! as Dictionary<NSString, NSString>
            var text = json["safe_title"]!
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.updateMe.text = text
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening is that your HTTP request is running on a background thread. When it calls the callback you provide, you're still on that background thread. In iOS **all UI work must be done on the main thread**. The easiest way to do this is by using GCD's `dispatch_async` like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    [weak self] in
    self?.updateMe.text = json["safe_title"]!
    return
}
```

So your entire function would look like:

```
func updateWithJson() -> Void {
    let req = Agent.get("http://xkcd.com/info.0.json")
    req.end({ (response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, data: Agent.Data!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        let json = data! as Dictionary<NSString, NSString>
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            [weak self] in
            self?.updateMe.text = json["safe_title"]!
            return
        }
    })
}
```

The bit about `[weak self] in` is so you don't create a [strong reference cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_92). The `return` at the end is there because you have a closure with only one expression in it. In that case, Swift will try to [implicitly return a value based on that statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_158) and in this case that's not what you want.

Comment: I tried the `dispatch_async` route but it still took a while. Let me try it again. I had to do `dispatch_sync` to make it work.

Comment: Okay, I must have been doing it wrong the first time. I changed it back to `dispatch_async` and now it works as desired. Thanks!

Comment: I also met this problem and fixed it according to you code, thanks